# Inheritance in java - something that i cannot understand

Tags: java

I have question regarding inheritance in Java that i cannot understand:

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class C
{
    public void foo(D d)
    {
         System.out.println("cd");  
    }
}

public class D extends C
{
    public void foo(C c)
    {
         System.out.println("dc");  
    }

    public void foo(D d)
    {
         System.out.println("dd");  
    }
}
```

And main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    C cd = new D();
    D dd = (D)cd;   
}
```

What is the type of each of `cd` and `dd` and why?

Comment: The object is `D`, at all time. Casting only *reduces the view* to an object, but doesn't change the object itself. So you could reduce the view to a `Dog` to `Animal`. It is still a `Dog` but you want the compiler to forget about that and handle it like its just an `Animal`. This makes it possible to add `Cat` and `Dog` to a `List<Animal>` and when you later get items of that list, they are still `Cat` and `Dog`, but you only know that they are `Animal`. With casting you can try to *lift the view* again. But you should check with `instanceof` before you try to cast a `Cat` to a `Dog`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two distinct types involved here:

1. type of the variable;
2. type of the object referred to by the variable.

The type of the variable is independent of the type of the object it currently happens to be referring to—and vice versa, the type of the object doesn't depend on the type of the variable through which it is accessed. Therefore, as you assign an object to another variable of a different, its type is not influenced.

So,

- the type of *variable* `cd` is `C`;
- the type of the *object* referred to by it is `D`.

Comment: Why cd is C ? what the new D() mean ?

Comment: `new D()` means you have created an object of type `D`.

Comment: The type of the `cd` variable is `C` because you have declared the type of the `cd` variable to be `C`.

Answer (score 1):

So we can introduce the concept of Inheritance like this.....

Certain from a preceding class and drag the features and qualities of its' , and create a new class like preceding class for our own, with features and qualities of preceding class..Then ,the preceding class will be the Super class,and the new class is will be the Sub class..

Ex:-The children have their parents' features and qualities.

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Form extends JFrame{

}
class Demo{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Form f1=new Form();
            f1.setSize(300,300);
            f1.setTitle("Form");
            f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(Form.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f1.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Also, some of the sentences are very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Will start my answer with below points:

1. Class D is extending class C, so class D is the child class of class C.
2. Left side variable is called the reference variable and right side assignment with new operator is called as Object.
3. First-line shows D (Child class) object is assigned to the reference variable of Parent class. **It means cd is the reference variable of type Parent which holds the object of Child class.** It means at Runtime, the compiler will check whether Child class is a type of Parent class, and If so, it will cast it and display the Child method output.
4. Whenever the foo method will be called on cd, it will call foo method present in Child class.
5. 2nd line shows D (Child class) reference variable dd holds the object of D(Child) class.

**That means.** cd which was the reference of class C(Parent) is now implicitly cast to class D(Child).
**Child class reference variable (dd) is again storing the object of Child class (D).**